# Generalisation of remainder thereom

Tags: polynomials

The [Remainder theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem), says that when the polynomial $P(x)$ is divided by $x-a$, the remainder is $P(a)$.

> What is the remainder when $P(x)$ is  divided by $x^2 +ax +b$?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Lagrange_interpolation

Answer (score 1):

$$P(x) = (x^2 +ax +b) Q(x) + vx +t $$
if $z_1 , z_2 $ are solutions of $x^2 +ax +b =0 $ the the coefficients $v, t $ you can find from the linear system of equations $$vz_1 +t =P(z_1 ) ,vz_2 +t =P(z_2 )$$

Comment: or you can just show $$P(x)\equiv P(-(x^2+(a-1)x+b))$$